# SimpleView Based app with id initWithFrame Not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have app to create a graph i have created a view based app and then add the code for creating graph in it but it does not disply the graph. If use same code to create a separate UIView then it works other wise not

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import "ECGraph.h"
  #import "ECGraphItem.h"
 @class GraphsViewController;
 @interface Display : UIView {

NSArray *percentages;

int myY;
ECGraph *graph;
ECGraphItem *item1;
ECGraphItem *item2;


   }
  @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray*percentages;

 -(void) setPercentageArray:(NSArray*) array;

 @end


 #import "Display.h"
 #import "ECGraph.h"
 @implementation Display
 @synthesize percentages;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
}
return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


CGContextRef _context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();



graph = [[ECGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500,-320,320, 200) withContext:_context isPortrait:NO];


item1 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];

item2 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];
/*
ECGraphItem *item1 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];

ECGraphItem *item2 = [[ECGraphItem alloc] init];*/

item1.isPercentage = YES;



item1.yValue=myY;




item1.width = 35;
item1.name = @"item1";

item2.isPercentage = YES;
item2.yValue =17;

item2.width = 35; 
item2.name = @"item2";



[graph setXaxisTitle:@"name"];
[graph setYaxisTitle:@"Percentage"];
[graph setGraphicTitle:@"Histogram"];
[graph setDelegate:self];
[graph setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0 green:220/255.0 blue:220/255.0 alpha:1]];



NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item1,item2,nil];


[graph drawHistogramWithItems:items lineWidth:2 color:[UIColor blackColor]];




}
```

I am adding this view in GraphsViewController but its not showing anything

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self createGraph];



percentages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"80",@"17", nil];

display = [[Display alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:display];

[display setPercentageArray:percentages];

}
```

Comment: where did you add the second block of code?  in TestingViewController?  and are you sure about that call to CGRectMake?  the parameters for that are x, y, width, and height.  you've got a y location of -320 and a height of 200.

Comment: @Nate i think Alexander is saying right we need separate UIView in ViewController to work for this but when i add that it does not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do the drawing in a separate `UIView` object and add it as a subview to your view controller's view. That's the way it is supposed to work.

> The UIView class uses an on-demand drawing model for presenting
>   content.

Source: [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)

as opposed to

> The UIViewController class provides the fundamental view-management
>   model for all iOS apps. ... A view controller manages a set of views
>   that make up a portion of your app’s user interface.

Source: [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Edit:

```
// ...
display = [[Display alloc] init];
CGRect dFrame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 320, 200); // change these to whatever values you need
[display setFrame:dFrame];
[self.view addSubview:display];
```

Comment: yes i also want this when use separate view it works fine but my problem is that i want to assign this view values dynamycially from TestingViewController

Comment: lets say i make another UIView how to add that view to myview

Comment: @user1392981 you can add view like [self.view addsubview:yourview]; but you have to give frame of that view. den add that in your view

Comment: yes i have added like this but not showing the items of the subview

Comment: @chinttu i have update my code see how i am adding UIView and why its not showing graph

Comment: u didnt gave frame of the display view give the frame and u can get your view like initwithframe:cgrectmake(0,0,100,100)

Comment: @user1392981 display = [[Display alloc] initwithframe:cgrectmake(0,0,100,100)]

Comment: @user1392981, you have to set a frame for the Display `UIView` and then add it as a subview.

Comment: display = [[Display alloc] initwithframe:CGRectMake(496,437,463,209)];

Comment: @Alexander it is giving error crash when use this-[Display initwithframe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d56c50
2012-05-15 12:06:49.765 Cerenia[1551:9203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Display initwithframe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d56c50'

Comment: You should use `[display setFrame:yourFrame];`; The code you are trying to use doesn't work because `initWithFrame:` is not a class method.

Comment: mean i may create a frame separate and acces it using this i am trying

Comment: @Alexander thanks it is showing now blank frame but not showing graph which is in Display view as shown in code

Comment: Are the values for the dimensions negative as your `graph`'s frame?

Comment: thanks it showing now i was doing all this for that i can give dynamic values to the graph which is created in the Display so will it now be easy to send values to UIView from view controller